# Image upload preview javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-app-engine, image-upload

I am trying to make a image preview before upload. But when i am trying to upload them, there are upload only the latest ones. 
**Example:** Firstly i upload 3 images(and it appears 3 file selected), then i want to upload 4 more images. And my problem is that it appears 4 images selected(not 7 images selected) but in  the image preview there are all of them.
I use python to upload them in the datastore and in the datastore there are only the latest images.

**Javascript**

```
//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
jQuery(function ($) {
var fileDiv = document.getElementById("upload");
var fileInput = document.getElementById("upload-image");
console.log(fileInput);
fileInput.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    var files = this.files
    showThumbnail(files)
}, false)

function showThumbnail(files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i]
        var imageType = /image.*/
        if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
            console.log("Not an Image");
            continue;
        }

        var image = document.createElement("img");
        // image.classList.add("")
        var thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
        image.file = file;
        thumbnail.appendChild(image)

        var reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = (function (aImg) {
            return function (e) {
                aImg.src = e.target.result;
            };
        }(image))
        var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        image.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(image, 100, 100)
        }
    }
}
});
});
//]]>
```

**Html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 medium-12">
        <input type="file" name='file' id="upload-image" multiple></input>
            <div id="thumbnail">
            </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**Python**

```
imagesnumber=len(self.get_uploads('file'))
while imagesnumber!=0: 
    image = self.get_uploads('file')[0]
    img = DateBase()
    img.blob_key = image.key()
    img.img_url = images.get_serving_url( image.key() )
    img.put()
    imagesnumber=imagesnumber-1
```

Comment: In your python script what is the value of imagesnumber?

Comment: In my python there are only the latest ones.

Comment: What happens when you don't add new pictures. Do the original 3 go through ok?

Comment: Could it be the original 3 file upload boxes are not in the form being submitted?

Comment: I thought at this but i don't know how i can put all files (old and new) toghether. My problem is how can i extract all files with python from a div.

Comment: Can you include your whole page, javascript and html. Maybe where the JS adds the div for the new file upload is different than where the initial 3 are.